# Return all rows from a table and indicate with a new column whether they exist or not in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, join

If I have 2 tables:

`TABLE_SEARCHFIELDS`:

```
 FieldID | FieldName
--------------------
 1       | MyField1
 2       | MyField2
 3       | MyField3
 4       | MyField4
 5       | MyField5
```

and

`TABLE_CUSTOMSEARCHFIELDS`:

```
 UserID  | FieldID
--------------------
 1       | 1
 1       | 2
 1       | 5
 2       | 2
 2       | 4
 2       | 5
```

and I would like to return all of the `Searchfields` from the first table, but would also like indicated whether that `Searchfield` is active for a particular user.

E.g. I want to query `UserID = 1` and get the result:

```
 FieldID | FieldName | Active
------------------------------
 1       | MyField1  | 1
 2       | MyField2  | 1
 3       | MyField3  | 0
 4       | MyField4  | 0
 5       | MyField5  | 1
```

What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would do this using `exists`:

```
select sf.*,
       (case when exists (select 1
                          from customsearchfields csf
                          where csf.userid = 1 and csf.fieldid = sf.fieldid
                         )
             then 1 else 0
        end) as Active
from searchfields sf;
```

Assuming you have no duplicate rows, you can also do this using a `left join`:

```
select sf.*, (case when csf.userid is not null then 1 else 0 end) as Active
from searchfields sf left join
     customsearchfields csf
     on csf.userid = 1 and csf.fieldid = sf.fieldid;
```